# contact form 7 - wordpress - user listing

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

Im trying to make a simple user listing in a dropdown select box using contact form 7
Anyone see what im doing wrong?
Just trying to simply obtain all the users and display them in the selection box. But im running into trouble when trying to work this into my contact form 7 plugin.

```html
wpcf7_add_shortcode('postdropdown', 'createbox', true);

function createbox(){
    global = $wpdb;
    $blogusers = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'display_name' ) ) );
    $output = "
        <select name='cursus' id='cursus' onchange='document.getElementById(\"cursus\").value=this.value;'>
            <option></option>";
    foreach ( $blogusers as $user );
     $output .= "<option value='$user'> $user </option>";
    endforeach;
    $output .= "</select>";
    return $output;
}
```

Any help would be great!
Brook

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of line 3

Answer (score 0):

To display the name you need to use `$user->display_name` as show in WordPress Codex for [`get_users`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

Also there is not need for `$wpdb` and its not declared correctly. You don't add `=` sign, check [Variable Scope in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)